# Sending GSM 7 bit message with more than 160 characters in Kannel 1.5.0

Tags: gsm, kannel

I have installed kannel 1.5.0 and i am trying to send GSM 7 bit message, when characters are  less or equal to 160 the message deliver correctly but when characters are greater than 160 , message is delivered with strange symbols and characters and thus become unreadable. I have enabled string concatenation to true and set max-messages to 15 in my kannel.conf

```
group = sendsms-user
username = gwanchi
password = "gwanchi"
default-smsc = SMSC2
concatenation = true
max-messages = 15
dlr-url = "http://gwanchi.site/reports?lclmsgid=1&id=%25F&phone=%25p&type=%25d&report=%25A"

group = sms-service
name = processmessages
keyword = default
max-messages = 15
concatenation = true
get-url = "http://gwanchi.site/inbox"
```

what should i do to be able to send GSM 7 bit message with more than 160 characters and the message to be delivered correctly in mobile phone. When sending the message i set coding=0 and character set utf-8